# How can I get data from in one thread from another thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple client-server program. In one thread GUI is running, when I click "connect" button on GUI, I connect to server in new thread, after some time I receive some data from server and I want to pass it to GUI - how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a reference to your GUI object to the reading thread, and have the reading thread invoke a method of the GUI instance when he has received the data.

If the GUI is a Swing GUI, you'll need to wrap the call into `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`:

```
Thread readingThread = new MyReadingThread(gui);
readingThread.start();
```

and in the reading thread:

```
String data = readData();
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        gui.dataHasBeenReceived(data);
    }
});
```

Note that [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is designed specifically for this kind of use-case.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and example code, which worked in my simple program perfectly. I've heard about SwingWorker, but I didn't want to read and learn whole class just to send one short string from one thread to another.

Answer (score 1):

Generally - by passing a callback object to the new thread, and whenever you have results, invoke that callback, which in turn updates the GUI.

The "callback" can be an object implementing a custom interface of yours, that takes the result as argument.

```
BackgroundThread background = new BackgroundThread();
backgroundThread.setCallback(new Foo() {
   public void updateGUI(Bar bar) {
        //...
   }
}
```

Than, when you have the information available in the background thread, you can just call:

```
getCallback().updateGUI(bar);
```